Databricks Asset Bundles: Disable Schedule of Jobs
I am using databricks asset bundles and have a lot of jobs with a schedule.
I want to have a target where the schedules are disabled, something like this:
targets:
  no-schedule:
    resources:
      jobs:
        *:
          schedule: null

I know I can disable it job by job but I want to do it simply for all jobs. Further, I am aware of the develop mode but it has additional constraints which I don't want to use.

You can use YAML features to apply configuration overrides globally and disable schedules for all jobs in Databricks Asset Bundles (DAB) for a particular target. Regretfully, DAB does not have an integrated wildcard configuration for overriding schedules in all jobs (*). To make the process simpler, you can accomplish this by use YAML anchors and aliases.
targets:
  no-schedule:
    resources:
      jobs: &disable_schedules
        job1:
          schedule: null
        job2:
          schedule: null
        job3:
          schedule: null


I dont want to rewrite all jobs in the target
